# ui:inputDate and SLDS

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system

The SLDS date picker depicted here looks lovely:
https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/datepickers/

The stock `ui:inputDate` is very functional and I like how it falls back to native date pickers on mobile. However it doesn't quite fit in with SLDS and it's not as pretty as the SLDS example (which comes without a matching component). Is there any off-the-shelf solution to get a pretty SLDS-style date picker that is nice and functional with data binding? I don't want us to have to spend much time rolling our own.

Comment: got any chance to look at this SLDS styled [datepicker](http://aljs.appiphony.com/#!/datepickers)? Personally i have used it in angular vf pages but i haven't tested with Lightning Component yet.And about the data binding you might need to manually wired it up using `onchange` event.

Comment: Frankly Lightning Locker has really broken a lot of jQuery based solutions... I could try it out but I have a feeling it's just not going to work well. The ideal would be something written directly for Lightning and not using additional libraries like jQuery and moment.js.

Comment: Hi @CharlesT That's very true!                                                                          Did you find any other workaround for the datepicker?

Comment: Nope. Probably just going to fall back on `ui:inputDate`. I just don't like how there are so many inner parts that make it hard to customize the style.